# Bing indexed pages decreased from 2400 to 2 in 5 days

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

Bing indexed pages decreasing rapidly..

Previously bing indexed pages was **2400 in search**.

Then I submitted sitemaps.

After 4-5 days of submitting site maps .. Bing index starts decreasing from 2400 to 1500, then 300 and then 30, **now only 2 pages are indexed**.

I don't see any crawl errors in webmasters or any other issues/ message in bing webmaster tools.

Is this normal ?

Comment: No its not normal unless you are blocking those pages via noindex in the source or robots but also if the content is considered thin, low value, duplicate or respun content then Bing may drop the index. It'd be helpful if you shared the URL